# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list | nodejs | `npm start`

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint

Running `npm start` is giving me a syntax error, shown in the output below.
I know how to fix a simple syntax error but I doubt that's the issue here. Looking through various forums didn't result in an answer for me.

```
[nodemon] starting `npm run lint && node src/app.js`

> server@1.0.0 lint C:\Users\brend\project\server
> node ./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js

C:\Users\brend\project\server\node_modules\.bin\eslint:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
      ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "lint"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 lint: `node ./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 lint script 'node ./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs server
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\brend\project\server\npm-debug.log
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Below is the package.json.

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js --exec \"npm run lint && node\" ",
    "lint": "node ./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js"
  },
```

Comment: Could you show us your package.json lint script ?

Comment: of course, how idiotic of me.

Comment: `sed` is not a standard Windows command. Does node.js or npm provide the `sed` command?

Comment: have you tried removing `node_modules` folder and running npm install again and then testing?


**Warning:** Make sure all the packages you used are in package.json before you do this

Comment: I don't think you should be combining `node` with `nodemon`. `nodemon` serves as a `node` daemon. Basically you should use it exclusively.
`"start": "nodemon -w src/app.js --exec \"npm run lint && node src/app.js \" "`

Comment: with `sed` you mean `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")` ? I'm not sure what that is honestly. I'm a complete noob when it comes to this stuff.

I've tried removing the `node_modules` twice, once with the recommended version of node and the latest one.

@JohnKennedy I've tried running that, it gives me a json parse error. Stating that "package.json must be actual JSON, not just javascript"

Comment: could you send the full code so I can have a look at it.

Comment: Both scripts and their respective debug logs are pasted here: https://pastebin.com/F6qf3HDc

Comment: I also have this error, but I only have 1 script in my scripts object

Answer (score 1):

Ugh.. Okay first thing I ran into was an error saying that `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I googled and came to the conclusion that I needed to put `node` before the script. This resulted in progress; namely that it actually ran the script. Turns out it was needed at the `"start"` script but not the `"lint"` script.

My package.json scripts now look like this:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js src/app.js --exec \"npm run lint && node\" ",
"lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js"
},
```

Which results in:

```
[nodemon] starting `npm run lint && node src/app.js`

> server@1.0.0 lint C:\Users\brend\project\server
> eslint **/*.js

hello
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

ps: Thank you for your help kind strangers!